# Как передать SQL-запрос в скрипт PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

На сайте есть БД MySQL. Надо выводить данные с разбивкой на страницы.

1. На основе заполнения формы поиска строится SQL-запрос.
2. Выводим первые 20 записей.
3. С помощью параметра LIMIT разбиваем запрос на страницы и делаем ссылки перехода на другие страницы...

Вопрос: как поступить с полученным запросом, т.е. передавать ли его в качестве параметра через GET или через POST, создавать глобальную переменную или записывать его в БД, либо строить его в каждой следующей странице заново, передавая туда все полученные в форме поиска параметры? Как сделать правильнее с точки зрения скорости работы и надёжности от SQL-иньекций?

Answer (score 2):

практика такова - в GET/POST передается  только номер страницы, далее по номеру высчитывается LIMIT & OFFSET и формируется запрос на каждой странице заново. 
Если запрос тяжёлый, т.е долго выполняется, то можно его  кешировать. Здесь есть несколько подходов.

Например, один из них:

взять 1000 строк запроса и положить его во временный файл, далее имя файла положить в кеш, а данные со страниц от 1-50 / по 20 строк на стр. использовать этот файл. Ну, если пользователь очень настырный и ему мало 1000 результатов поиска (обычно после первой просмотра 10 стр успокаиваются), то придётся взять следующие 1000 строк и т.д.

недостатки: нужно сделать инвалидатор кеша, внешний скрипт, который запускается по крону и уничтожает все старые файлы (которые имеют время создания более 30 мин после текущего).
я такую чистилку кеша запускал раз в сутки ночью.

как вариант используем мемкеш, но тут часть времени съест сериализация большого массива, хотя это капелька в море. тут думать про инвалидацию не нужно, все за тебя сделает мемкеш.

некоторые используют БД как кеш - на мой взгляд глупо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно записывать фильтр в сессию, а потом менять только страницу.

Соответственно, из плюсов - данные передаются один раз, + до закрытия браузера можно в любой момент продолжить поиск. Желательно учесть кнопку сброса и формирование фильтра в сессии проводить в числе первых операций.

Минусов пока не вижу, разве что будет проблемно ссылку передать, но ее можно из этого же фильтра сформировать и вывесить отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Наиболее безопасный способ передавать на сервер все необходимые пораметры из формы фильтра. А сам запрос генерировать и выполнять на сервере. В противном случае Вы создадите серьезную уязвимость.

Answer (score 0):

Как будете передавать гет или пост роли не играет, я так понимаю передаваться будет только цифровое значения для лимита, тогда обрамляйте вашу переменную функцией intval(), это спасет вас от иньекции, для остальных значений (не цифр) советую использовать mysql_real_escape_string().

Тут выше еще говорили про форму-фильтр, это имеет права на жизнь только как дополнения к моим словам выше, хакеру подделать информацию отправляемую формой не составит большого труда.

Comment: Всем спасибо!
To KiTE: запрос в любом случае строится на сервере в PHP-скрипте. Я понял так, что его лучше каждый раз при смене страницы строить заново.
To Sh4dow: я думал над этим. А что если куки будут отключены?
To tranceman: передавать надо не только limit, а и весь запрос тоже (о чем и вопрос). Можно построить запрос 1 раз, а потом проверять по одному параметру строился он уже или нет и в зависимости от того, какая сейчас page - добавлять к запросу LIMIT с соответствующими коэффициентами. Или каждый раз при смене страницы всё строить заново, теряя время на логику и проверки.
Спасибо всем

Comment: Я так понял, Вы собирались генерить условную (WHERE) часть запроса на клиенте. Это и есть уязвимость.

Comment: To KiTE: нет-нет, ничего на клиенте не делаю! Речь идет только о PHP. Запрос строится на сервере, задача - правильно организовать его разбивку на страницы. Не хотелось при переходе на следующую страницу опять всё строить заново, как это надо делать при новом поиске (этот запрос-то уже сделан).